# Mock GPS location issue

Tags: java, android, gps, mocking, location

I'm developing an APP that get user specified latitude,longitude, and altitude, then fake this GPS location on the phone, and show that I am at that location in google map. I have the required permission on manifest file and mocked location is enabled in developer settings.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//lm.clearTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider);
lm.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 0, 10);
lm.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
mockLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider); // a string
mockLocation.setLatitude(Integer.parseInt(latitude.getText().toString()));  // double 
mockLocation.setLongitude(Integer.parseInt(longitude.getText().toString())); 
mockLocation.setAltitude(Integer.parseInt(altitude.getText().toString())); 
mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
lm.setTestProviderLocation( mocLocationProvider, mockLocation);
```

But looks like my GPS location is not changed at all on google map, what is the problem?

Update: I just installed an app called "fake GPS location" on my phone and that app works fine, but I still don't know what's wrong with my code, but I think mine is a formal way to achieve this.

Update #2: Although some of similar applications can run on my phone, but I found some exceptions, http://www.cowlumbus.nl/forum/MockGpsProvider.zip, this app is not working on my phone. can someone help me with this issue? millions of thanks! I'm not getting any error message when setting the location each time.

Update#3 : I noticed that this app is fairly old, so it does not run on 4.1. if so, how to do the same thing in the new version? my phone is samsung galaxy s3, hope it helps.

Update#4: for your info, the code from app in my update#2 is:

```
package nl.cowlumbus.android.mockgps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MockGpsProviderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MockGpsProviderActivity"; 
    private static final String MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX = "GpsMockProviderIndex";

    private MockGpsProvider mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
    private Integer mMockGpsProviderIndex = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Use saved instance state if necessary. */
        if(savedInstanceState instanceof Bundle) {
            /** Let's find out where we were. */
            mMockGpsProviderIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, 0);
        }

        /** Setup GPS. */
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){ 
            // use real GPS provider if enabled on the device
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
        else if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
            // otherwise enable the mock GPS provider
            locationManager.addTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, false, false,
                    false, false, true, false, false, 0, 5);
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, true);
        }  

        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

            /** Load mock GPS data from file and create mock GPS provider. */
            try {
                // create a list of Strings that can dynamically grow
                List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

                /** read a CSV file containing WGS84 coordinates from the 'assets' folder
                 * (The website http://www.gpsies.com offers downloadable tracks. Select
                 * a track and download it as a CSV file. Then add it to your assets folder.)
                 */         
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("mock_gps_data.csv");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                // add each line in the file to the list
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    data.add(line);
                }

                // convert to a simple array so we can pass it to the AsyncTask
                String[] coordinates = new String[data.size()];
                data.toArray(coordinates);

                // create new AsyncTask and pass the list of GPS coordinates
                mMockGpsProviderTask = new MockGpsProvider();
                mMockGpsProviderTask.execute(coordinates);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // stop the mock GPS provider by calling the 'cancel(true)' method
        try {
            mMockGpsProviderTask.cancel(true);
            mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        // remove it from the location manager
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // store where we are before closing the app, so we can skip to the location right away when restarting
        savedInstanceState.putInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, mMockGpsProviderIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // show the received location in the view
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        view.setText( "index:" + mMockGpsProviderIndex
                + "\nlongitude:" + location.getLongitude() 
                + "\nlatitude:" + location.getLatitude() 
                + "\naltitude:" + location.getAltitude() );     
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }


    /** Define a mock GPS provider as an asynchronous task of this Activity. */
    private class MockGpsProvider extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        public static final String LOG_TAG = "GpsMockProvider";
        public static final String GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER = "GpsMockProvider";

        /** Keeps track of the currently processed coordinate. */
        public Integer index = 0;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {         
            // process data
            for (String str : data) {
                // skip data if needed (see the Activity's savedInstanceState functionality)
                if(index < mMockGpsProviderIndex) {
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }               

                // let UI Thread know which coordinate we are processing
                publishProgress(index);

                // retrieve data from the current line of text
                Double latitude = null;
                Double longitude = null;
                Double altitude= null;
                try {
                    String[] parts = str.split(",");
                    latitude = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
                    longitude = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
                    altitude = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e) { break; }        // no data available
                catch(Exception e) { continue; }                // empty or invalid line

                // translate to actual GPS location
                Location location = new Location(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
                location.setLatitude(latitude);
                location.setLongitude(longitude);
                location.setAltitude(altitude);
                location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                location.setLatitude(latitude);
                location.setLongitude(longitude);
                location.setAccuracy(16F);
                location.setAltitude(0D);
                location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                location.setBearing(0F);

                // show debug message in log
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

                // provide the new location
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, location);

                // sleep for a while before providing next location
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);

                    // gracefully handle Thread interruption (important!)
                    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        throw new InterruptedException("");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }

                // keep track of processed locations
                index++;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onProgressUpdate():"+values[0]);
            mMockGpsProviderIndex = values[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Is this line correct: the string is a double coordinate and you parse an Integer, avoid inlining do it step by step, and look/debug if you set the correct value:  "mockLocation.setLatitude(Integer.parseInt(latitude.getText().toString())); // double

Comment: I think it is correct because if it is integer, it will automatically converted to double in java programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: I added the following code to set my current location and it can successfully show up in google map application.

```
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);
location.setBearing(bearing);
location.setSpeed(speed);
location.setAltitude(altitude);
location.setTime(new Date().getTime());
location.setProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
location.setAccuracy(1);
```

Conclusion: If you want to use mock location service in the new version of android, you have to set every attribute by yourself.

Comment: To get mock locations working, I also had to run location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()).  This is in the example code on the Google website, but it isn't mentioned in the documentation.  If I do not set this (minAPI=17) property, mock locations fail silently on my Galaxy S5 running 4.4.2

Comment: @Ben: Thank you so much. I have been trying this for the whole day. After adding the elapsedRealtimeNanos line, my code works like a charm.