# Prevent mocked GPS position from reverting to real values

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm developing a mock location application for myself and had good success so far.
I can set de desired location and it is shown in google maps.

My Problem is that sometimes the location switches to the real location provided by the gps module of my nexus 7 LTE (2013) with Android 6.0.1.

I set the location service to device only and i use the provider LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

This is what i use to set the desired location:

```
newLocation.setLatitude(lat);
newLocation.setLongitude(lon);
newLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
newLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
newLocation.setSpeed((float) (speed / 3.6));
accuracy = (float) generateRandomDouble(ACCURACY_MIN, ACCURACY_MAX);
newLocation.setAccuracy(accuracy);
newLocation.setAltitude(altitude);
```

What did i try to solve this:

1. setting a new location every 200ms
2. setting the time stamps into the future
3. setting the accuracy always to 1

Similar questions to location mocking like [Mock GPS location issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613703/mock-gps-location-issue) didn't help either.

What i noticed is that those jumps occur less often if the gps can't get a good signal.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to avoid those 'jumps'?

Comment: I think you should update the title. It doesn't seem to properly reflect your question.

Comment: I tried changing it. Feel free to revert.

Comment: thanks this is much better

Comment: what about the solution. I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for that?

Comment: no, no solution but i don't need this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to block the internal GPS with aluminium foil.
That's not the solution i was hoping for but this works fine no more jumps.